# How do I properly return sanitized data to Javascript application from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, decode, encode

There's a lot of information on how to sanitize data, but I can't find anything on returning sanitized data. I have user input going into my database so I sanitize it, but now I'm returning it to my application and feel like the whole point of sanitizing is so no injection or anything happens on the front end.

Basically, I'm sanitizing input from the user in my php script with filter_var with the FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS option:

```
filter_var($variables, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)
```

and then, when another function is called, I'd return the same data, say the name of a person and the data comes back as so:

Data In:

```
 Mc'Example & Person
```

Data Returned When Called from Javascript application:

```
 Mc&#x27;Example &#x26; Person
```

My question is, let's say I called html_entity_decode() to this, wouldn't that leave the front-end open for an attack? How do I get around this?

**Clarification:**

IncredibleHat clarified for me, but I'm worried about the front-end being affected by

```
<script> bad stuff </script> John Example Smith
```

kind of input since I'm decoding back to the front-end.

Comment: Call `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` on the data before returning it.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't that open up the javascript application to an attack if I'm decoding the encoded attack string?

Comment: JavaScript won't fall victim to SQL injection, it isn't a database server.  Your JavaScript needs its own validation against completely different attacks.

Comment: @DaveS I believe he is concerned about someone inputting `<script>...stuff..</script>My Name is Bobby` ... and it returning that value back into html and thus becoming a hazard. His question didn't mention SQL Injection attacks as the issue.

Comment: @IncredibleHat That's correct. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @DJSweetness also htmlentities and htmlspecialchars are not decoding, they are encoding of the sort. Encoding certain characters to be HTML/JS Friendly (not literal).

Comment: Ah, raw PHP echo of code from the database becoming part of the page.  I'd have rejected that as an invalid name before storing it.  Bobby <script> should be checked for by both the PHP validation and the JavaScript validation in case someone bypasses the browser page.  Also, when doing a PHP echo you should be HTML encoding anyway so &lt;script&gt; is what you echo

Comment: But bobbyMc&#x27; you would have not discarded am I right?

Comment: Okay, so I should put some sanitization on the front-end and do the htmlspecialchars() from my php code?

Comment: @user3647971 I mean, I didn't want to because it's their name, but if it's safer to discard anything that's not a simple character, then I'll go that route.

Comment: Your question is actually really good. You should not decode as html before showing it client-side

Comment: When doing a PHP echo you could use HTML encoding so "Bobby &lt;script&gt;" is what you'd echo

Comment: `strip_tags` is helpful when dealing with the inbound data before storing (to get rid of stupid things people try). And then yes, wrapping the echo'd fields with `htmlspecialchars` is a good help there as it kills tag brackets pretty solid.

Comment: Yup they should be as entities, but if you have input fields that they need to populate there you can revert them back

Comment: strip_tags does not help with the issue at hand tho, user could use html entities as input and if you have html decode to show the data in the first place they would then turn to valid html without ever being stripped

Comment: strip_tags does help. He shouldn't be using html_entity_decode for output to the page (unless he fully trusts the data he is decoding, which is never in case of user input). If its coming in already encoded (user trying to avoid strip_tags), then doing htmlspecialchars on that pre-encoded input is still 'safe', it just makes a mess visually... but its still safe from execution ;)

Comment: I don't think you should be sanitizing when storing in the DB. You store the raw data in the DB, and use `htmlentities()` when displaying it on a web page. If they put tags into the data, it will then be displayed literally instead of being executed, and you won't have any XSS problems.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't that open up my database to sql injection? Regardless, I'm using pg_prepares for sql protection, but then we are kind of running into the same problem with malformed data, no?

Comment: @DJSweetness If you use a prepared statement you're safe from SQL injection.